# In Angular collapse directive, if change contents, collapse div doesn't update height

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

We have an Angular UI Bootstrap Collapse directive in our Angular app. When we change the contents of the collapse, we would like the div to update appropriately.

However, apparently the height is set in the style when the collapse is opened and does not update if we change the contents of the collapse element. If I change the contents while it is open, then the height does not change. This seems like it should be taken care of automatically. Is this a known issue and what is a good way to get around it?

Using Angular 1.2.2, UI 0.9.0, and Bootstrap 2.3.2

Comment: Could you provide a plunk with a reproduce scenario? Normally collapsible div gets height: auto when it gets expanded, so should grow with more content.

Comment: Other way around. When it's already expanded, if we change the contents, it is not adjusting it's height. It looks like the height is only being set at expansion time and is not responding to events related to its contents changing. Will try with 3.0.x. I didn't realize that I could upgrade. I had been keeping it at 2.3.2 because of the old restriction on 0.7.0

Comment: we _will_ need a plunk to help more. Normally collapsible div should have height: auto and standard bootstrap CSS classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 0.9.0 of the angular-ui/bootstrap is not compatible with Bootstrap 2.3.2 CSS. 0.8.0 is the last version that supports Bootstrap 2.3.2 CSS. You either need to use 0.8.0 or migrate to Bootstrap 3.